# Javascript functions var global

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use this script:
https://github.com/peol/node-spotify

And I can't figure out how to make

```
spotify.search({ type: 'track', query: 'dancing in the moonlight' }, function(err, data){
   return data; 
});
```

data globaly available?

i tried like butin `var data =`  in front of that but it didn't help

Comment: Is that call asynchronous?

Comment: You should have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196 to understand how asynchronous code works. While you can make the value global, you have to pay attention to *when* you are accessing it. As demonstrated in the answer, passing the response to a callback is a better approach. Or use promises, there are Node libraries for them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need that data to be available "globally" in the current file scope, just define another var outside that call:

```
var myData;
spotify.search({ type: 'track', query: 'dancing in the moonlight' }, function(err, data){
  myData = data;
});
```

If you need it to be available globally across your Node process, then do the following:

```
spotify.search({ type: 'track', query: 'dancing in the moonlight' }, function(err, data){
  global.myData = data;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the global one.

Comment: FYI: Using `global` works, but is considered bad coding style.

Comment: That solves the problem of *where* you can read the variable, but it doesn't help with the problem of *when* you can read it. That's the entire reason for using callbacks in the first place. The next question will be "Why does `myData` have an `undefined` value even though I set it in the callback?" :-) (Answer: the callback hasn't run yet.) Of course if the rest of the code takes this into account it will be OK, but still how do you know when `myData` becomes available? That's why the usual way is to take some action directly in the callback or in a function it calls.